# Continuous database reading for wpf application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have one web application in which user summit the information and then, the information comes to the database.

So, the scenario, when the WPF application started it read the database and populate the data grid, but, when the new row is added (which is basically done when there is an new entry done when the user has entered the value from the web) I don't get that value automatically, it doesn't update the data grid I have to close the WPF page and then start it again to see that alert how to get that data dynamically always,

or do you think I should have API endpoint tell me the both solution and also which is the best.

I cannot change the webform application as it is hosted by another client.

Here, I have thought so of doing it which I am sure, not the best way.

Adding a flag column referred to as a "change tracking" to the database table for tracking changes. This flag column can be a boolean (bit) column that is set to true (1) when a new row is added or an existing row is updated and then set to false (0) after the data is retrieved by your WPF application.

Add a Flag Column: Add a flag column (e.g., IsNew) to database table if it doesn't already exist. This column should default to true(1) when a new row is added.
Database Trigger: Create a database trigger that sets the flag column to true when a new row is added or an existing row is updated.
WPF Application: Application to query for rows where the flag column is true, retrieve the data, and then set the flag column to false to mark the row as processed.
Here's a simplified example of how your WPF application code might look:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;
using System.Windows;

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private string connectionString = "your_connection_string_here";
    private Timer timer;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Initialize the timer
        timer = new Timer(10000); // Poll every 10 seconds
        timer.Elapsed += async (sender, e) => await CheckForNewRowsAsync();
        timer.Start();
    }

    private async Task CheckForNewRowsAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                await connection.OpenAsync();

                // Query the database for rows where IsNew = 1 (true)
                string query = "SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE IsNew = 1";
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
                    {
                        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
                        await Task.Run(() => adapter.Fill(dataSet)); // Execute the query asynchronously

                        if (dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            // Process the new rows and update your data grid or perform other actions
                            foreach (DataRow row in dataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
                            {
                                // Process the row
                            }

                            // After processing, mark the rows as processed (IsNew = 0)
                            await MarkRowsAsProcessedAsync(connection);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle exceptions, log errors, etc.
        }
    }

    private async Task MarkRowsAsProcessedAsync(SqlConnection connection)
    {
        // Update the flag column to mark rows as processed
        string updateQuery = "UPDATE YourTable SET IsNew = 0 WHERE IsNew = 1";
        using (SqlCommand updateCommand = new SqlCommand(updateQuery, connection))
        {
            await updateCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(); // Execute the update asynchronously
        }
    }
}
```

The timer periodically checks for rows where IsNew is true (1) in the database.
It processes the new rows, and after processing, it updates the IsNew column to false (0) to mark the rows as processed.

Any suggestions

The viewmodel

```
using LIT.Core.Mvvm;
using LIT.Modules.TabControl.Commands;
using Prism.Mvvm;
using SQLDataAccessLayer.Models;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace LIT.Modules.TabControl.ViewModels
{
    public class ItineraryCommentsTabViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        #region field
        private readonly ItineraryCommentsTabCommands _commentsTabCommands;

        private ObservableCollection<Commentsmodel> _commentsCollection;

        private Commentsmodel _commentsmodel;

        private string _itineraryId;

        private string _loginId;

        private string _userName;
        #endregion

        #region ctor

        public ItineraryCommentsTabViewModel()
        {
            _commentsTabCommands = new ItineraryCommentsTabCommands(this);
            _commentsCollection = new ObservableCollection<Commentsmodel>();
        }
        #endregion

        public ItineraryCommentsTabCommands CommentsTabCommands => _commentsTabCommands;
        public ObservableCollection<Commentsmodel> CommentsCollection
        {
            get { return _commentsCollection; }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _commentsCollection, value);
                _commentsTabCommands.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            }
        }

        public Commentsmodel Commentsmodel
        {
            get { return _commentsmodel; }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _commentsmodel, value);
                _commentsTabCommands.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            }
        }

        public string LoginId
        {
            get { return _loginId; }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _loginId, value);
                _commentsTabCommands.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            }

        }

        public string ItineraryId
        {
            get { return _itineraryId; }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _itineraryId, value);
                _commentsTabCommands.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
                _commentsTabCommands.RetrieveCommand.Execute();
            }
        }

        public string UserName
        {
            get { return _userName; }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _userName, value);
                _commentsTabCommands.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
                //_commentsTabCommands.RetrieveCommand.Execute();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The view

```
<UserControl x:Class="LIT.Modules.TabControl.Views.ItineraryCommentsTab"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:LIT.Modules.TabControl.ViewModels" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewmodels:ItineraryCommentsTabViewModel}"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:behavior="clr-namespace:LIT.Core.Behaviors;assembly=LIT.Core"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/LIT.Core;component/Styles/TextBoxStyles.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/LIT.Core;component/Styles/ButtonStyles.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/LIT.Core;component/Styles/TabItemStyles.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Border Background="White" Padding="10" Margin="10">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="200"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="200"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <TextBlock FontFamily="Calibri" Foreground="#25304c" FontSize="16" Padding="0,5,10,15" VerticalAlignment="Center">Comment List</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource btnBlue}" 
                            Command="{Binding CommentsTabCommands.AddCommand}"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Calibri" 
                            Height="30" Background="Transparent" FontSize="14" BorderBrush="Transparent" 
                            Foreground="#FF579F00" FontWeight="Bold"  MaxWidth="50" Width="50" 
                            BorderThickness="2,0,0,0" Cursor="Hand"  
                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="/LIT.Core;component/Media/Images/plus.png" Width="13" VerticalAlignment="Center"></Image>
                            <Label Foreground="#FF579F00" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Center">Add</Label>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">

                        <DataGrid x:Name="CommentDataGrid"
                              MinWidth="1250"
                              MinHeight="500"
                              MaxHeight="300"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding CommentsCollection , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding Commentsmodel, Mode=TwoWay}"
                              HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#D8D9D9" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#D8D9D9" 
                              BorderBrush="#D8D9D9" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#fff" Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                              CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" behavior:NewSingleClickDataGridBehavior.EnableSingleClickEditing="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Booking ID" MinWidth="115" Width="*">
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#252E39" />
                                            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri"/>
                                        </Style>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding BookingId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Calibri"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Supplier Name" MinWidth="140" Width="*">
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#252E39" />
                                            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri"/>
                                        </Style>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SupplierName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="5 0 0 0" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Calibri"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Supplier Ref No" MinWidth="135" Width="*">
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#252E39" />
                                            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri"/>
                                        </Style>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SupplierRefNo, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Left" Padding="5,0,5,0" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Calibri"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Comments" MinWidth="490" Width="*">
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#252E39" />
                                            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri"/>
                                        </Style>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Comments, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Left" Padding="5,0,5,0" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Calibri"></TextBlock>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Comments, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Left" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Calibri"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Commented by" MinWidth="100" Width="*">
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#252E39" />
                                            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri"/>
                                        </Style>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Commentedname, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Calibri" Padding="5,0,5,0">

                                            </TextBlock>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Comment On" MinWidth="120" Width="*" >
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#252E39" />
                                            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri"/>
                                        </Style>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100">
                                                <DatePicker   x:Name="Txtsaledate" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SelectedDate="{Binding CommentedOn, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontFamily="Calibri"  Height="24" FontSize="14" BorderBrush="#FFA1A1A1" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" >
                                                    <DatePicker.Background>
                                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                            <GradientStop Color="White"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                    </DatePicker.Background>
                                                </DatePicker>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel>
                                                <DatePicker   x:Name="Txtsaledate" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  SelectedDate="{Binding CommentedOn, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontFamily="Calibri"  Height="24" FontSize="14" BorderBrush="#FFA1A1A1" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" >
                                                    <DatePicker.Background>
                                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                            <GradientStop Color="White"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                    </DatePicker.Background>
                                                </DatePicker>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="60"  Header="Delete"   Width="*">
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#252E39" />
                                            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri" />
                                        </Style>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                                <Button Name="btnPassengerDelete"
                                                    FontFamily="Calibri"  
                                                    Background="Transparent"  Foreground="#FF003D" 
                                                    BorderBrush="Transparent" 
                                                    Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},
                                                                Path =DataContext.CommentsTabCommands.DeleteCommand}"
                                                    VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                                    Content="&#10006;" Cursor="Hand" Padding="12,1,12,1"  FontSize="14" >
                                                    <!--<Image Source="../Images/delete_black.png" Width="16" Height="16" />-->
                                                </Button>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The commands

```
using LIT.Core.Mvvm;
using LIT.Modules.TabControl.ViewModels;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal;
using Prism.Commands;
using SQLDataAccessLayer.DAL;
using SQLDataAccessLayer.Models;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace LIT.Modules.TabControl.Commands
{
    public class ItineraryCommentsTabCommands : CrudOperations<ItineraryCommentsTabCommands>
    {
        private readonly ItineraryCommentsTabViewModel _viewModel;
        private readonly Commentsdal _commentsdal;

        public DelegateCommand AddCommand { get; set; }
        public DelegateCommand DeleteCommand { get; set; }
        public DelegateCommand RetrieveCommand { get; set; }

        public DelegateCommand SaveCommand { get; set; }

        public ItineraryCommentsTabCommands(ItineraryCommentsTabViewModel viewModel)
            : base("Add", "Delete", "Retrieve", "Save") 
        {
            _viewModel = viewModel ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(viewModel));
            _commentsdal = new Commentsdal();

            _viewModel.PropertyChanged += ViewModel_PropertyChanged;

            AddCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteAdd);
            DeleteCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteDelete);
            RetrieveCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteRetrieve);
            SaveCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteSave);
        }

        public new event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        protected override void ExecuteAdd()
        {
            var newComment = new Commentsmodel
            {
                Commentsid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                SupplierName = string.Empty,
                SupplierRefNo = string.Empty,
                Comments = string.Empty,
                CreatedBy = _viewModel.LoginId,
                ModifiedBy = _viewModel.LoginId,
                IsDeleted = false,
                DeletedBy = _viewModel.LoginId,
                CommentedOn = DateTime.Now,
                Itineraryid = _viewModel.ItineraryId,
                CommentedBy = _viewModel.LoginId,
                Commentedname = _viewModel.UserName
            };

            _viewModel.CommentsCollection.Add(newComment);
        }

        protected override void ExecuteDelete()
        {
            if (_viewModel.Commentsmodel != null)
            {
                // Find the selected item in the CommentsCollection and remove it
                Commentsmodel selectedComment = _viewModel.Commentsmodel;
                _viewModel.CommentsCollection.Remove(selectedComment);

                // Delete the item from your data store (e.g., database) using your DAL
                _commentsdal.DeleteCommentsDetails(selectedComment.Commentsid, selectedComment.DeletedBy);

                // Optionally reset the _viewModel.Commentsmodel property
                _viewModel.Commentsmodel = null;
            }
        }

        protected override void ExecuteSave()
        {
            foreach(Commentsmodel comment in _viewModel.CommentsCollection) 
            {
                comment.CommentedBy = _viewModel.LoginId;
                _commentsdal.SaveUpdateCommentsDetails("I",comment);
            }
        } 
        
        protected override void ExecuteRetrieve()
        {
            // Retrieve data from the database using your DAL
            //Guid itineraryId = Guid.Parse("6120f3c4-1b10-4270-b92d-073564c3851f");
            //var comments = _commentsdal.RetriveCommentsDetails(itineraryId);

            //// Clear the existing collection and add the retrieved data
            //_viewModel.CommentsCollection.AddRange(comments);

            Guid itineraryId = Guid.Parse(_viewModel.ItineraryId);
            if (itineraryId != Guid.Empty)
            {
                // Retrieve data from the database using your DAL with the provided itineraryId
                var comments = _commentsdal.RetriveCommentsDetails(itineraryId);

                //foreach (Commentsmodel comment in comments)
                //{
                //    comment.comm = _viewModel.UserName;
                //    comments.Add(comment);
                //}

                // Use the Dispatcher to update the UI collection on the UI thread
                _viewModel.CommentsCollection.AddRange(comments);
            }
        }

        private void ViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }
}
```

The MODEL

```
namespace SQLDataAccessLayer.Models
{
    public class Commentsmodel : PropertyChangeNotifier
    {
        public string Commentsid { get; set; }
        public long BookingId { get; set; }
        public string SupplierName { get; set; }
        public string SupplierRefNo { get; set; }

        private string _comments;
        public string Comments
        {
            get
            {
                return _comments;
            }

            set
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SupplierName) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(SupplierRefNo))
                {
                    OnPropertyChangedWithNotification(ref _comments, value, customMessage: $"Comments respect to the supplier reference number {SupplierRefNo} has been changed to {value}");
                }
                else
                {
                    SetProperty(ref _comments, value);
                }
            }
        }
        public string Itineraryid { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you displaying your data ? Is the `DataGrid` bound to a property we can't see in your snippet above ? The code above should work. You may want to consider implementing async in your query methods as I think that each time the timer ticks, it'll block your application until the data is done loading.

Comment: @CodeJunkie Updated any help will be alot

Comment: The code you posted is indeed useful but I still don't see how the rows are added to your collection. I've noticed the initial value of `CommentCollection` is null which means you are creating it somewhere else which is not shown here. Also provide a snipped of how the data is added to the collection.

Comment: @CodeJunkie what happens is, the retrieve command from commands is coupled with the viewmodel observable collection Comments model; DAL that comes from the SQL populates the model.